# edit core data model objects in a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am trying to edit existing objects in Core Data storage. When i edit each object's attribute without a loop this works fine, but when I try to do it in a `for` loop, only my last object gets new attributes. 
Here is the code I use to edit objects without a loop. This code works fine):

```
NSFetchRequest *songsRefreshRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Music"];
songsRefreshRequest.predicate = nil;
songsRefreshRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                      ascending:YES
                                                                       selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
NSError *frError;
NSArray *fetchedSongs = [self.context executeFetchRequest:songsRefreshRequest error:&frError];
fetchedSongs ? : NSLog(@"Error in fetch while refreshing songs: %@", [frError localizedDescription]);


NSString *song1path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Beautiful-birds-song-in-the-morning" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSString *song2path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Birds-singing-relaxation" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSString *song3path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Morning Melody" ofType:@"mp3"];

Music *song1 = (Music *) [fetchedSongs objectAtIndex:0];
Music *song2 = (Music *) [fetchedSongs objectAtIndex:1];
Music *song3 = (Music *) [fetchedSongs objectAtIndex:2];

song1.name = @"Beautiful-birds-song-in-the-morning";
song2.name = @"Birds-singing-relaxation";
song3.name = @"Morning Melody";

song1.path = song1path;
song2.path = song2path;
song3.path = song3path;
```

Here is the code I use to edit song's attributes in a loop (code below somehow edit a path for only the last object (song3 in my case), other object's `path` attribute becomes `NULL`. And I can't figure out why):

```
for (Music *iterSong in fetchedSongs){
    NSString *iterSongName = [iterSong valueForKey:@"name"];
    iterSong.path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: iterSongName ofType:@"mp3"];
}
```

I have already tried to change `for each` to `for (int i=0; i<[fetchedSongs count]; i++)` this didn't help. Cycle repeats as many times as many songs are in the model and only changes the last song's path. Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

P.S. The whole loop code:

```
for (Music *iterSong in fetchedSongs){
        //Music *iterSong = (Music*) [fetchedSongs objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"inerSong.name = %@", iterSong.name);
        NSLog(@"inerSong.oldPath = %@", iterSong.path);

        NSString *iterSongName = [iterSong valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *iterSongPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: iterSongName ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSLog(@"iterSongPath (string) = %@", iterSongPath);
        iterSong.path = iterSongPath;
        NSLog(@"iterSong.newPath = %@", iterSong.path);

    }

    if ([self.context hasChanges]){
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"error while saving context after refreshing song paths: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you check the value of iterSongName in the for loop?

Comment: I NSLog'ed iterSong.name and it stays right for every song in the loop

Comment: Can you post the complete code for the loop version? When do you actually look for the path values?

Comment: @Dirk I NSLog path values inside the loop. And they don't appear outside the loop because my AVAudioPlayer that uses those paths only works with the last song. I added the whole loop code to question.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with the loop or with Core Data, but I still don't have an idea what's wrong. What happens if you set song1.name etc. and then ask for the paths using these names (not in the loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved this way:
I removed all the hyphens from files' names. And the code started to work fine with the same loop. Also I converted files from mp3 to wav. But I suppose that problem existed because file can't include hyphen in its name.

Thanks everyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you run that loop inside the NSManagedObjectContext [performBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) method. Second, you need to [save your changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html) to your NSManagedObjects context after you edit your objects.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] == NO) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

**Swift:**

```
do {

        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Tried to use loop inside `performBlock:` method and tried to save context right after making changes - no luck so far, still `pathForResource:` method finds path only for the 3rd song. Thanks for answer anyway!

Comment: Since you didn't update inside performBlock and neither did save when you asked the question, I would guess there is something wrong with your method of saving and updating items. I am not 100% exactly where it is tho it takes time to investigate. But you need to check on the methods I described in my answer this is how you should edit and save objects, never outside of your context.